# typescript, react и интерфейсы - организовать правильную структуру

Tags: reactjs, typescript, интерфейс, typescript-типы

использую связку react и typescript

описываю разные типы (состояния компонент react, элементы массивов и т.д.) в качестве интерфейсов, которые затем использую в коде

подскажите такие технические вопросы (сам с этим только сейчас стал сталкиваться и хотелось бы сразу понять какой подход более правильный):

1. если интерфейс используется только в одном компоненте react, стоит ли его всё выносить в отдельный файл
2. стоит ли логически связанные интерфейсы выносить в отдельный файл или все интерфейсы хранить в одном файле
3. как правильно выносить интерфейсы в отдельный файл - ведь для них тоже наверное `export` надо будет прописывать, а потом при `import` указывать, какой интерфейс требуется - или это не обязательно?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Берём твой вопрос, заменяем термин интерфейс на [абстрактный класс](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html#abstract-classes).

Теперь тебе вопрос.

Будешь ли ты выносит в отдельный файл `abstract class A` если:

1. в этом же файле он расширяется классом B?
2. в двух/трех/... других файлах он расширяется классами B/C/...?
3. ты вообще уверен что обязан в JavaScript плодить по файлу на конструктор?

### style guide

возьмём для примера

> An unofficial TypeScript Style Guide

- https://basarat.gitbook.io/typescript/styleguide#interface

от [Basarat](https://mvp.microsoft.com/ru-ru/PublicProfile/5002417?fullName=Basarat%20%20Ali%20Syed) - четырежды MVP

раздел interface

> **Don't** prefix with `I`

говорит он.

С чем, лично я, не согласен. Использование префикса в интерфейсах и типах, например `$`, может реально облегчить жизнь.

### OOP (IMHO)

Читая умные книжки больших дядек - помни, что ООП это решение проблем с которыми ОНИ столкнулись в рамках их

- языка
- средств сборки
- проблем с памятью
- и т.д. и т.п.

### -,- подведу итог

#### Если ты импортируешь *только* типы - используй это

```
import type {} from 'someModule'
```

#### Важно: declaration-merging !!!!

- https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html

Если `interface` `class` `namespace` объединяются в одну сущность - однозначно, они должны быть в одном файле.

```
export class Album {
  label: Album.AlbumLabel;
}
export namespace Album {
  export class AlbumLabel {}
}
```

```
export interface Fish {
    fly(): void
}
export abstract class Fish {

}
```

#### Ответы из "опросника"

0. Ты же Используешь `.tsx` ? Да !!!?

1. Пфф, конечно же нет!
2. "все интерфейсы хранить в одном файле" - а чо они вообще забыли в отдельном файле? Помни - интерфейс это просто комментарий, расширенная версия JSDoc. Их стоит выносить в отдельный файл, мм..., как функции, только в том случае, если они используются в разных местах проекта.
3. > ведь для них тоже наверное export надо будет прописывать

   По моему мнению - очевидно, что с такими вопросами мы тебя отправим читать документацию и учить язык... Не забудь почитать про `import type {} from 'someModule'`

---

Comment: хороший ответ :) спасибо. С абстрактным классом очень хороший пример

Comment: спасибо, старался. Этот вопрос интересен в контексте: _тимлид накидал джунам/верстальщикам интрефейсов - как организовать структуру проекта_. Думаю, это зависит от команды: количество человек, распределения ролей/ответственности, а кроме вьюшки есть ещё и модель ...

Comment: в каждой команде по своему - вот иллюстрация этой мысли https://github.com/airbnb/javascript